# Read and parse a tab delimited file PHP

Tags: php, python

I worked out this Python script to read a tab delimited file and place the values where the line starts with `'\t'` in a `array`. The code which I used for this:

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import os   

file = sys.argv[1]

f = open(file, 'r')
direc = '/dir/to/JSONs/'
fileJSON = sys.argv[1]+'.json'

key1 = OrderedDict()
summary_data = []
full_path = os.path.join(direc,fileJSON)

Read = True 
for line in f:
        if line.startswith("#"):
            Read = True

        elif line.startswith('\tC'):
            Read= True

        elif line.startswith('\t') and Read == True:
            summary = line.strip().split('\t')
            key1[summary[1]]=int(summary[0])
            Read = True    

summary_data.append(key1)
data = json.dumps(summary_data)
with open(full_path, 'w') as datafile:
    datafile.write(data)
print(data)
```

The data which I am parsing:

```
# BUSCO was run in mode: genome

    C:98.0%[S:97.0%,D:1.0%],F:0.5%,M:1.5%,n:1440

    1411    Complete BUSCOs (C)
    1397    Complete and single-copy BUSCOs (S)
    14  Complete and duplicated BUSCOs (D)
    7   Fragmented BUSCOs (F)
    22  Missing BUSCOs (M)
    1440    Total BUSCO groups searched
```

But, I need this code in PHP.. I have managed to open the file in PHP and to read this! Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get the point of Read variable - it is always True in your code, the last 'elif' statement would be enough. Below is php version of your script

```
<?php
    $fileName = $argv[1];
    $dir = '/dir/to/JSONs/';
    $fullPath = $dir . $fileName . '.json';

    $data = [];
    $output = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    while (($line = fgets($output)) !== false) {
        if ($line[0] == "\t") {
            $summary = explode("\t", trim($line));
            if (count($summary) > 1) {
                $data[$summary[1]] = (int)$summary[0];
            }
        }
    }

    $strData = json_encode([$data]);
    $input = fopen($fullPath, 'w+');
    fwrite($input, $strData);
    echo $strData;
```

Comment: Thank you! This returned `Undefined offset: 1`?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine did you add file name in cli command? Like 'php script.php fileWithTabs'

Comment: Yes! I used a `var_dump($summary)` which returned: `array(1) { [0]=> string(44) "C:98.0%[S:97.0%,D:1.0%],F:0.5%,M:1.5%,n:1440" }`.. so it didn't skip that line.. How could I make sure that the first tab delimited line is skipped?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine I've just updated the code for that case

Comment: I have caught the expection by adding a loop which checks `/tC`! Thank you very much. I will except this code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read variable was unnecessary in your code so i deleted it and replaced something you can see results at console :

```
<?php
$file = $argv[1];
$direc = '/dir/to/JSONs/';
$key1 = [];
$summary_data = [];
$full_path = $direc.$file.'.json';
$file_handler = fopen($full_path, 'r');
if($file_handler){
    while(($line = fgets($file_handler)) !== false){
        if($line[0] == "#" || substr($line, 0 , 2) == "\tC" || empty($line) == true){
            echo 'line found : '.$line;
            continue;
        }else{
            $summary = explode("\t", $line);
            echo 'summary : '.print_r($summary,true);
            $key1[str_replace(["\r","\n"], '', $summary[2])] = (int) $summary[1];
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'Couldn\'t open file.';
    exit();
}
array_push($summary_data, $key1);
$data = json_encode($summary_data);
fclose($file_handler);
file_put_contents($full_path, $data);
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the `$summary[2]` to `$summary[1]` and `$summary[1]` to `$summary[0]`, but it returns `Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: I did it for solving undefined offset problem use it as i wrote. You should use as $summary[2] and $summary[1]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this in php, fgetscsv lets you specify a delimiter (it's not just for commas):

```
$file_resource = fopen( $file, "r");
fgetcsv($file_resource, 4096, "\t")
```